# Optional RewriteRule parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I combine these RewriteRules into one single line, with each parameter being optional?

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ index.php?_page=$1&_sub=$2&_area=$3&_ex=$4 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ index.php?_page=$1&_sub=$2&_area=$3 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/ index.php?_page=$1&_sub=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/ index.php?_page=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^ index.php [NC,QSA]
```

I believe that `.*` automatically requires the next block otherwise it's captured too, so you can replace that with `[^/]+` however when I do that on one line (removing all but the first rule), it stops working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be disappointed because there's no solution of what you're asking for.

Moreover for each (n+1) subdir the variable name changes... so there's definitely no solution.

Anyway you can reduce your RewriteRules using a thing like:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)(/([^/]*))?/ index.php?_page=$1&_sub=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

which makes the second argument empty *but matches both one or two arguments*.

Comment: Well this works, `RewriteRule ^app/?([\w]+)?/?([\w]+)?/?([\w]+)?/?((.*?)+)?$ index.php?_page=$1&_sub=$2&_area=$3&_ex=$4 [NC,QSA,L]`

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I meant to tick that!

Comment: @James Your suggestion *may* works but validates more possibilities than what you're looking for (`app/word1-word2` shoud be valid  (didn't test it) even though it's not what you may want)

Answer (score 0):

Your rexexp `^app/?([\w]+)?/?([\w]+)?/?([\w]+)?/?((.*?)+)?$` is semantically different to your starting cascade.

- Where did the app with the optional / come from?
- How do you wan to process non-word characters such as "."?
- The non-greedy operator ([\w]+)**?**/ is redundant
- What about additional parameters pseudo-directories?

Anyway in regexp terms the greedy `([^/]*)` is better as this will work properly with a `/?`.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?^([^/]*)/?^([^/]*)/?^([^/]*)$ index.php?_page=$1&_sub=$2_area=$3&_ex=$4 [NC,QSA,L]
```